# Checking if async task has finished, somewhere down the road

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, async-await

I have the following extension method:

```
Note.PreloadAsync(); //returns Task
```

This method calls a rest endpoint and updates the Content property of the Note object.

I call this method at a certain point in my application. Then, sometime when I need to call the Content property of the Note object, I want to check if the PreloadAsync method has finished (9/10 of ten times it has, but when the users interacts with the app quickly, the Content is not yet loaded).

What is the best way to approach this?

I have tried a lot of approaches but either the Content property never get properly updated (its always NULL) or calling the PreloadAsync().IsCompleted property hangs at runtime or is not found (error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use that

```
var task = Note.PreloadList(); 
Task.ContinueWith(()=>{// your action here will be called when the task finished.});
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

or if PreloadList is async just change the core to this: await Note.PreloadList(); The next line will be called after task completion. The calling method in this case must be async as well.